# Need to plot a number of graphs in a grid from a for loop creation

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a straightforward for loop that loops through datasets in a set and plots the resultant scatterplot for each dataset using the code below;

```py
for i in dataframes:
    x = i['cycleNumber']
    y = i['QCharge_mA_h']

    plt.figure()
    sns.scatterplot(x=x, y=y).set(title=i.name)
```

This plots the graphs out as expected, one on top of the other. Is there a simple way to get them all to plot onto a grid for better readability?

As an example lets say we have the following datasets and code:

```py
data1 = {'X':[12, 10, 20, 17], 'Y':[9, 8, 5, 3]}  
data2 = {'X':[2, 13, 7, 21], 'Y':[17, 18, 4, 6]}  
data3 = {'X':[9, 19, 20, 3], 'Y':[6, 12, 4, 1]}  
data4 = {'X':[10, 13, 15, 1], 'Y':[6, 12, 5,16]}  
data5 = {'X':[12, 10, 5, 3], 'Y':[18, 7, 21, 7]}  
data6 = {'X':[5, 10, 8, 17], 'Y':[9, 12, 5, 18]}

df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3=pd.DataFrame(data3)
df4=pd.DataFrame(data4)
df5=pd.DataFrame(data5)
df6=pd.DataFrame(data6)

lst = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]

for i in lst:
    plt.figure()
    sns.scatterplot(x=i['X'], y=i['Y'])
```

This returns an output of each scatterplot called printing on top of another i.e. stacked. I cant upload a shot of what that output looks like as it runs across multiple pages (this tidy output that I can capture and display is exactly what it is I'm trying to achieve).

I want it to be in a grid, lets say a 2x3 grid given it has 6 plots. How do I achieve this?

Comment: (1) Could you supply some test data, (2) what your current output looks like, and maybe (3) what you'd like it to look like? e.g. single column of plots, single row, grid-like, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ways you could do this.

## The Original

```py
import matplotlib  # 3.6.0
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np  # 1.23.3
import pandas as pd  # 1.5.1
import seaborn as sns  # 0.12.1


# make fake data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "cycleNumber": np.random.random(size=(100,)),
    "QCharge_mA_h": np.random.random(size=(100,)),
})

# single plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(df, x="cycleNumber", y="QCharge_mA_h", ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: original]

## With `matplotlib`

```py
# make 5 random data frames
dataframes = []
for i in range(5):
    np.random.seed(i)
    random_df = pd.DataFrame({
        "cycleNumber": np.random.random(size=(100,)),
        "QCharge_mA_h": np.random.random(size=(100,)),
    })
    dataframes.append(random_df)

# make len(dataframes) rows using matplotlib
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=len(dataframes))
for df, ax in zip(dataframes, axs):
    sns.scatterplot(df, x="cycleNumber", y="QCharge_mA_h", ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image: mpl]

## With `seaborn`

```py
# make 5 random data frames
dataframes = []
for i in range(5):
    np.random.seed(i)
    random_df = pd.DataFrame({
        "cycleNumber": np.random.random(size=(100,)),
        "QCharge_mA_h": np.random.random(size=(100,)),
    })
    dataframes.append(random_df)

# make len(dataframes) rows using matplotlib

# concat dataframes
dfs = pd.concat(dataframes, keys=range(len(dataframes)), names=["keys"])

# move keys to columns
dfs = dfs.reset_index(level="keys")

# make grid and map scatterplot to each row
grid = sns.FacetGrid(data=dfs, row="keys")
grid.map(sns.scatterplot, "cycleNumber", "QCharge_mA_h")
plt.show()
```

[image: sns]

## With `col_wrap=3`

```py
# make 5 random data frames
dataframes = []
for i in range(5):
    np.random.seed(i)
    random_df = pd.DataFrame({
        "cycleNumber": np.random.random(size=(100,)),
        "QCharge_mA_h": np.random.random(size=(100,)),
    })
    dataframes.append(random_df)

# make len(dataframes) rows using matplotlib

# concat dataframes
dfs = pd.concat(dataframes, keys=range(len(dataframes)), names=["keys"])

# move keys to columns
dfs = dfs.reset_index(level="keys")

# make grid and map scatterplot to each column, wrapping after 3
grid = sns.FacetGrid(data=dfs, col="keys", col_wrap=3)
grid.map(sns.scatterplot, "cycleNumber", "QCharge_mA_h")
plt.show()
```

[image: col_wrap]